# Uploading image to Facebook and including it in feed post from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, facebook

I was working on an iphone app where users create images (think like a paint program); then they have an option to post it to Facebook: the image would be uploaded to the users albums and simultaneously a post would appear on their stream ("Hey, look what I just made with app X, get it here; etc).

This used to work just dandy, but it seems that Facebook no longer allows images hosted on their domain to be used in stream posts: FBCDN image is not allowed in stream is the error message.

Anyone have a workaround method for doing this kind of "upload and stream post in one shot" kind of thing? I know I could have the users upload all their created images to my own server and use that in the feed post...but that should be totally unnecessary. It shouldn't require an extra server for a user to draw a picture in a paint app and then upload to FB with a corresponding feed post about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI - Base64 encoded image URL are also not allowed :(

Comment: I'd recommend ShareKit. Painlessly adds fb/twitter/tumblr/email/etc sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424141/how-to-use-fbconnect-dialog-method-to-post-a-uiimage-to-my-wall) and learned that it's now a 2-step process where you upload the image to an album, then include a link to that in the feed.  The answer is complicated, so please check over at that link.  If you find it helpful, please up-vote that answer.  (Feel free to up-vote/accept this one, too, but I understand that's sort of cheating ;)